# bash Syntax Error: Unaccepted Token Elif

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I got this message after I ran a simple script:

> line 9: syntax error near unexpected token elif line 9: elif [ $sales -le 20000 ];

my code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Please enter the how much sales you have done"
    read sales
    if [ $sales -le 5000 ];
    then
       echo "your profit is $[$sales*0.25]"
    elif [ $sales -le 10000 ];
       echo "your profit is $[$sales*0.1]"
    elif [ $sales -le 20000 ];
       echo "your profit is $[$sales*0.15]"
    elif [ $sales -le 40000 ];
       echo "your profit is $[$sales*0.2]"
    else
       echo "your profit is $[$sales*0.25]"
    fi
```

Comment: You are missing the `then`s

Comment: you you right, thanks :)

Comment: http://shellcheck.net would have caught these errors for you and then, once you fixed those, a number of other issues.

Comment: quote your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're missing `then` after `elif`
2. You cannot do floating point math in bash.

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please enter the how much sales you have done: " sales
if [ $sales -le 5000 ]; then
   pp='0.25'
elif [ $sales -le 10000 ]; then
   pp='0.1'
elif [ $sales -le 20000 ]; then
   pp='0.15'
elif [ $sales -le 40000 ]; then
   pp='0.2'
else
   pp='0.25'
fi
echo "your profit is " $(bc -l <<< "$sales * $pp")
```

Comment: is there another way to do floating point math in bash?

Comment: No native BASH doesn't allow floating point math. You need to use an external tool like `bc`, `awk` etc.

Comment: I see, thank you very much !